# Use dependant subscriptions in Iron-router WaitOn and use them in helper functions

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

When doing the following implementation , i get problems because it's look like the data is not available in client side:

In The global configuration of Iron-router , i subscribe to "notifications" publication .
Then i fetch the notifications, and i collect the IDs of elements based on type.
Then i subscribe to the publications using the collected IDs.

In a template that displays the notifications details, i loop over notifications via Notifications.find() , and then depending on the type of notifications, i do :
Questions.findOne(_id) or Answers.findOne(_id) by i am getting undefined exception when i try to access the elements fields.

```
Router.configure({
      layoutTemplate: 'layout',
      loadingTemplate: 'loading',
      waitOn: function() { 
      Meteor.subscribe('notifications', function() {
      var notifications = Notifications.find().fetch();
        var questionsIds = _.map(_.filter(notifications, function (notif) {
        return notif.targetObjectType == 'QUESTION';
      }), function(q) { return q.targetObjectId});

     var answersIds = _.map(_.filter(notifications, function (notif) {
     return notif.targetObjectType == 'ANSWER';
     }), function(q) { return q.targetObjectId});

     Meteor.subscribe('notificationsAnswers', answersIds);
     Meteor.subscribe('notificationsQuestions', questionsIds);
```

How is it possible to wait for the "nested" subscriptions to be ready to use them in helper functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to move this code :

```
var notifications = Notifications.find().fetch();
        var questionsIds = _.map(_.filter(notifications, function (notif) {
        return notif.targetObjectType == 'QUESTION';
      }), function(q) { return q.targetObjectId});

     var answersIds = _.map(_.filter(notifications, function (notif) {
     return notif.targetObjectType == 'ANSWER';
     }), function(q) { return q.targetObjectId});

     Meteor.subscribe('notificationsAnswers', answersIds);
     Meteor.subscribe('notificationsQuestions', questionsIds);
```

to a onBeforeAction hook in the same global iron-router config like this :

```
onBeforeAction : function() {

var notifications = Notifications.find().fetch();
        var questionsIds = _.map(_.filter(notifications, function (notif) {
        return notif.targetObjectType == 'QUESTION';
      }), function(q) { return q.targetObjectId});

     var answersIds = _.map(_.filter(notifications, function (notif) {
     return notif.targetObjectType == 'ANSWER';
     }), function(q) { return q.targetObjectId});

     Meteor.subscribe('notificationsAnswers', answersIds);
     Meteor.subscribe('notificationsQuestions', questionsIds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, have you tried using `Deps.autorun ('notificationsAnswers' with a Session variable)`, and on your function notifications return along with `Session.set()`?

So you only `waitOn` Questions, and once find the `q.targetObjectId`, set the Session of answer will then trigger its subscription according.